# SQL Return a list of column names where the columns have different values across multiple records within a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone point me to the right way on how to tackle the below problem in SQL (SQL Server 2012)?

In table A there are objects (OID) listed for several groups (GID). Each object is described by a given set of attributes (Col_A .. Col_F).

For every group, I would like to list those attributes that have different values across all objects of the group. An empty list would indicate that the group have the same attribute values for all its objects.

Given: Table A showing 3 groups with a variable number of objects having the same structure.

| GID | OID | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | Col_E | Col_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | C1 | 33 | 2 | No | Green | **7** | Peter |
| G1 | C2 | 33 | 2 | No | Green | 1 | Peter |
| G1 | C3 | 33 | 2 | **Yes** | Green | 1 | Peter |
| G1 | C4 | 33 | 2 | **Maybe** | Green | 1 | Peter |
| G1 | C5 | 33 | 2 | No | Green | 1 | Peter |
| G2 | C1 | 33 | 2 | No | Blue | 1 | Mary |
| G2 | C2 | 33 | **1** | No | Blue | **2** | Mary |
| G2 | C3 | **34** | 2 | No | Blue | 1 | Mary |
| G3 | C1 | 33 | 9 | No | Blue | 1 | Ben |
| G3 | C2 | 33 | 9 | No | Blue | 1 | Ben |
| G3 | C3 | 33 | 9 | No | Blue | 1 | Ben |

Result set:

| Group | Discrepancies |
| --- | --- |
| G1 | Col_C, COL_E |
| G2 | Col_A, Col_B, Col_E |
| G3 | empty |

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select gid,
       trim(leading ',' from
                (case when min(col_a) <> max(col_a) then ',col_a' else '' end ||
                 case when min(col_b) <> max(col_b) then ',col_b' else '' end ||
                 case when min(col_c) <> max(col_c) then ',col_c' else '' end ||
                 case when min(col_d) <> max(col_d) then ',col_d' else '' end ||
                 case when min(col_e) <> max(col_e) then ',col_e' else '' end ||
                 case when min(col_f) <> max(col_f) then ',col_f' else '' end ||
                ) ) as exceptions
from t
group by gid;
```

Two notes:

1. These type of string operations vary by database, so you may need to tweak this for your database.  The above is Standard SQL.
2. None of your values have `NULL`s.  You don't specify what to do with them.  That above just ignores `NULL` values.

In the most recent versions of SQL Server, this is most simply written as:

```
select gid,
       concat_ws(',',
                case when min(col_a) <> max(col_a) then 'col_a' end,
                case when min(col_b) <> max(col_b) then 'col_b' end,
                case when min(col_c) <> max(col_c) then 'col_c' end,
                case when min(col_d) <> max(col_d) then 'col_d' end,
                case when min(col_e) <> max(col_e) then 'col_e' end,
                case when min(col_f) <> max(col_f) then 'col_f' end
               ) as exceptions
from t
group by gid;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, comparisons between max and min might be the hint I looked for.

Comment: Incidentally, the more obvious `case when count(distinct col_a) > 1` nearly always performs slower, I wish the optimizer would work this out